# How to force an automatic reload of the library from inside IPython notebook

Tags: python, ipython, python-import

I'm just learning IPython Notebook, using a pre-existing Python library I've written. At the beginning of my notebook, I'm importing it in the normal way.

However, I'm still modifying this library. I notice that changes I'm making to it don't seem to be reflected, even when I reload the notebook in the browser.

How can I force a reload of the library from inside IPython notebook?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the magic [`autoreload`](http://ipython.readthedocs.org/en/stable/config/extensions/autoreload.html?#module-IPython.extensions.autoreload) to get your module refreshed automatically as you edit it.

For instance, if you develop a module called `mylibrary`:

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 1
%aiimport mylibrary
```

will automatically reload the module `mylibrary`.

You can ask to get all modules automatically reloaded with:

```
%autoreload 2
```

Comment: And if you prefer to do it manually rather than reloading everything automatically, [importlib.reload()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload) is what you want.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was looking for.